# Mouse.OverrideCursor when some functions are running

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `WPF` application, and I want to hide the mouse cursor. Hence, I tried to do the following in the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
```

and I also tried this, as found in a thread here, in App.xaml.cs:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    if (Mouse.OverrideCursor != Cursors.None) Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
});
```

My application runs in fullscreen mode.
The problem is the cursors is indeed hidden until I call some "long-running" functions like this:

```
SmtpClient.Send();
```

When I call that function the "waiting" cursor appears, and it revert back to the "none" one when it has finished.

How to avoid this behavior?

Comment: That's an environmental issue, the SmtpClient class does not mess with the mouse cursor.  Could be anti-malware, easy to test by disabling it.  Could be the shell stepping in when you hang the UI thread for more than 5 seconds, the window title changes to "Not responding".

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to hide the cursor no matter the origin of the "issue"?